# fork fails while creating a daemon

Tags: c, fork

I have a C program which is invoked with variable arguments. This program forms commands using the arguments and then forks to create a child process. However, I see that the `fork()` command fails when the arguments to the program are higher in number.

Any clue why this would happen?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   FILE *logfile;
   int other=0;
   int i, pid;
   char *conn="conntrack -E";
   char *logger="logger -t log-conntrack -p daemon.notice";
   char *fother="grep -vE 'tcp|udp|icmp'";
   char cmd[1024];
   int length = 0;
   char * temp_cmd = cmd;

   for (i=1; i<argc; i++) {
   printf("for loop\n");
      switch(argv[i][1]) {
         case 'p': if (i+1 < argc && argv[i+1][0] != '-') {
                            if (strncmp(argv[i+1], "other",
                                        strlen(argv[i+1])) == 0) {
                                  other=1;
                                  snprintf(cmd, sizeof (cmd), "%s", conn);
                                  length = strlen (cmd);
                                  temp_cmd = cmd + length;
                                  i++;
                            } else if ((strncmp(argv[i+1], "tcp",
                                             strlen(argv[i+1])) == 0) ||
                                       (strncmp(argv[i+1], "udp",
                                             strlen(argv[i+1])) == 0) ||
                                       (strncmp(argv[i+1], "icmp",
                                             strlen(argv[i+1])) == 0)) {
                                  snprintf(cmd, sizeof (cmd), "%s%s%s", conn, " -p ", argv[i+1]);
                                  other=0;
                                  length = strlen (cmd);
                                  temp_cmd = cmd + length;
                                  i++;
                            }
                    }
                   break;
case 'e':
                   if (i+1 < argc && argv[i+1][0] != '-') {
                           if ((strncmp(argv[i+1], "NEW",
                                             strlen(argv[i+1])) == 0) ||
                                       (strncmp(argv[i+1], "UPDATES",
                                             strlen(argv[i+1])) == 0) ||
                                       (strncmp(argv[i+1], "DESTROY",
                                             strlen(argv[i+1])) == 0)) {
                                  if (other == 1) {
                                        snprintf(temp_cmd, sizeof (cmd) - length, "%s%s%s%s%s%s%s", " -e ", argv[i+1], " -o id", " | ", fother, " | ", logger);
                                        cmds[pcounter] = malloc(strlen+1);
                                        strcpy(cmds[pcounter],cmd);
                                        pcounter++;
                                     } else if ((strncmp(argv[i-1], "tcp",strlen(argv[i-1]))==0) &&
                                                (strncmp(argv[i+1], "UPDATES",strlen(argv[i+1])) == 0)){
                                        snprintf(temp_cmd, sizeof (cmd) - length, "%s%s", " -e ", argv[i+1]);
                                     } else {
                                        snprintf(temp_cmd, sizeof (cmd) - length, "%s%s%s%s%s", " -e ", argv[i+1], " -o id", " | ", logger);
                                        cmds[pcounter] = malloc(strlen+1);
                                        strcpy(cmds[pcounter],cmd);
                                        pcounter++;
                                     }
                                  length = strlen (cmd);
                                  temp_cmd = cmd + length;
                                  i++;
                            }
                    }
                   break;
         case 's': if (i+1 < argc && argv[i+1][0] != '-') {
                           if ((strncmp(argv[i+1], "SYN_RECV",
                                             strlen(argv[i+1])) == 0) ||
                                       (strncmp(argv[i+1], "ESTABLISHED",
                                             strlen(argv[i+1])) == 0) ||
                                       (strncmp(argv[i+1], "FIN_WAIT",
                                             strlen(argv[i+1])) == 0) ||
                                       (strncmp(argv[i+1], "CLOSE_WAIT",
                                             strlen(argv[i+1])) == 0) ||
                                       (strncmp(argv[i+1], "LAST_ACK",
                                             strlen(argv[i+1])) == 0) ||
                                       (strncmp(argv[i+1], "TIME_WAIT",
                                             strlen(argv[i+1])) == 0)) {
                                  snprintf(temp_cmd, sizeof (cmd) - length, "%s%s%s%s%s", " --state ", argv[i+1], " -o id", " | ", logger);
                                  cmds[pcounter] = malloc(strlen+1);
                                  strcpy(cmds[pcounter],cmd);
                                  pcounter++;
                                  length = strlen (cmd);
                                  temp_cmd = cmd + length;
                                  i++;
                            }
                    }
                   break;
     }
    }
    daemonize();
}
```

ulimit -a output is -

```
ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 16382
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited


free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           502        123        379          0         19         72
-/+ buffers/cache:         31        471
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Comment: The best way to get answers to such questions is to show some code, preferably a runable example.

Comment: Please post your code. 99 times out of 100, issues like these are due to implementation bugs rather than bugs in the functionality of an API.

Comment: The most obvious thing would be you're hitting some resource limit. But since you (a) haven't posted code; (b) **haven't even provided `errno`/`perror` from after the failed fork**, it's hard to provide much help.

Comment: posted code, it works fine on one system, but fails on another.

Comment: You didn't post the code which you state fails (fork() ?) -- could you try to print the errno and/or perror when the failure occurs?

Comment: fork: Cannot allocate memory, this is the error for fork.

Comment: i am running this program on a 256 bytes memory VM. That is the problem, thanks al.

Comment: If you have solved the problem, answer your own question (if you think the information could be useful to others) and accept it. If you think there is no point, perhaps remove it. But don't leave it open and apparently unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is fork wasn't having enough memory to allocate to the child processes. I increased the memory of the VM on which I was running the program and it worked.